# Where can i download banner/slider/header landscape background images?

Tags: website-design

I've looked all over google  , and i can't find any images that would fit right.
I'm looking for something like this http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB02634G3
or http://unslider.com/.
I really hope you know what i want. Is there a website i can download free banner/slider images? I want those landscape , blurred , HD photos of nature or city or people.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be shopping

Comment: Using the term 'panoramic' should help to find wide photos. As it stands this question is too broad. Good luck with your search.

Comment: See [Where can I get images for commercial use?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6799/where-can-i-get-images-for-commercial-use/6823)

Answer (score 2):

[stock.xchng](http://www.sxc.hu/) is very usefull for that type of situation. There's contents about everything.

## [Stock.XCHNG](http://www.sxc.hu/)

> Browse through the categories of our huge gallery containing over 350.000 quality stock photos by more than 30.000 photographers! Need a wallpaper for your desktop or illustration for your blog? Need a pic for your commercial website design? Looking for inspiration? Have a look around.

To get the blurred effect, if you find the image you want, but without it, you can always give the image a "blur effect" on your favourite image edit program.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try searching through [Flickr's Creative Common section](http://www.flickr.com/creativecommons/).  If you want to search for something on Flickr in regards to Creative Common go to `advanced search` and this will be at the bottom:

[image]