# Where can I find a background image for a 11" x 17" printed brochure?

Tags: print-design, resolution, stock-images, resource-recommendations

Creating an 11x17 brochure and require background images. Where can I purchase images of suitable quality/size to use for this purpose?

Comment: Hi pixelbabe, welcome to GD.SE! Have you tried searching any stock websites..?

Comment: I have not - do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Remember to use the watermarked images as "comps" for size and position and when you get the short list of usable ones, after whatever approval process, then go for the proper size based on placement. That way, you don't waste cash on a full-bleed image you wound up using at 5 inches

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6799/where-can-i-get-images-for-commercial-use

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew states, Stock image websites are a good resource for things like these. You can find stock sites in any price range, from free (eg. http://www.freeimages.com/, https://unsplash.com/) to outrageously expensive (http://www.gettyimages.com/) and everything in between. Try and google around to find something that fits your taste and wallet.

If it is designed backgrounds you are looking for, any stock site will have lots of them. Try entering 'background graphic' as a search term and you'll find some nice stuff just about anywhere.

For some more offbeat backgrounds, I like using http://www.textures.com/, which has hi-res pictures of all kinds of patterns and structures. It's originally intended for use in 3D environment design to skin the polygons, but I find it a real trove of background graphics.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I am looking for a "watery" kind of background for one brochure, and an "industrial/equipment" feel for another so the texture site might give interesting choices for the industrial...