# Graphic illustration design software for a person without knowledge in drawing

Tags: software-recommendation, illustration, resource-recommendations

I want to explain some things in my presentation which need an authentic illustration with a specific dress, for example, a person holds certain things or works with them in different positions (bending, etc.). Assuming my knowledge in drawing from 1 to 10 is 1, is there a graphic software that helps to do it easily?

N.b. It doesn't matter for me if it's 2D or 3D.

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question?

Comment: 1. Because there were no answers (except for your single comment). I understood maybe it wasn't clear what I'm looking for. 2. Because I think the current question explains more what I want. 3. because I didn't want to multiply question on this site. 4. Yes, maybe I should edit it, but it already was old and without answers, so I decided to open a new question)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. @UbiquitousStudent - You can edit a question and add more details to improve it. There's no need to delete it and repost. Please don't do that again.

Answer (score 4):

Design and/or Illustration is a *profession*.

Like any profession there are some things one can often do themselves without any actual training. It's not like it takes a PhD to understand what looks good to you or in order for a person draw.

However, like any profession the more specialized you want the results to be the more knowledge of the profession you will need. It may be entirely possible to find a series of illustrations on some [stock image site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6799/where-can-i-get-images-for-commercial-use) that fits your needs. Or to find images you can piece together to meet your needs, assuming you have *some* skill at image editing. But if you get *overly specific* - i.e. I need *my* product being held in the left hand of a figure facing towards the right - then you start breaching territory that *requires* skills to actually create such an image.

No software is going to compensate for an *actual* artist or designer. **If there were such software, all artists would be out of work.** You can find some generic human posable software packages such as [Poser](https://www.daz3d.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Search%20%7C%20Non-Brand%20%7C%20Tier%201%20%7C%20US&utm_content=Poser%20Software&utm_term=poser%20software&utm_matchtype=b&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIwviL043y6QIVUj2tBh1AZgmjEAAYASAAEgKFj_D_BwE) or cartoon packages such as [ToonBoom](https://www.toonboom.com/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIxLn73Y3y6QIVBh6tBh0wAQqWEAAYASAAEgJQzfD_BwE). However, even looking in that area there *will be* a **learning curve** to using any such software. Which all goes back to *why* there are professionals in the field.

Only you can decide what works for you and what you find acceptable, but overall **no** there is no software which will work as a substitute for the artistic mind of a human.

Comment: Right even if we would posit that a system could do so it would devaluate the image now you need sjill to decide either tinyer details or better strategies altogether. The only way skill can be taken out if tgere is no benefit to be gained for any action.

Comment: Anyway maybe op is looking for fiverr :)

Comment: @jooja: right there after freeware: you actually *do* get exactly what you pay for.

Answer (score 2):

Realistically speaking no, its not possible to gain something without expending some work. So with absolutely no skill you can not get anything done.

There is a category of software that might help: Most known of these is Poser. Essentially its a software that has pre made drawings that you can yourself pose. However this does not work well with your desire to make custom clothes. But thats ok technically 3D modeling is not drawing so all 3D fits your wish.

Then again if poser like software are too complicated for you then im afraid there is nothing you can do.

PS drawing skill of 1 would be a toddler, skill of 7 any adult should maser in a few months.

Comment: So you think it's better to start learning drawing than expecting to such software? That start sounds to me as a good idea.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent i think you allready know how to draw. I still havent seen a single early school/kidergarten child old who couldn't draw.

Comment: Ok,  let's say if I want to draw a person holding objects,  with specific coltural cliths,  I'd not want to see (& show) it on my presentation)

Answer (score 2):

- Does buying the tools to fix a car instantly make you a car mechanic?
- Does inheriting a million dollars instantly make you an investor in the stock market?

### No & no.

Skill is unfortunatelly something you need to learn, even with the tools on the table.

What I recommend you try is to look at stock sites and - not sure but maybe - you can find the exact type of artwork you're looking for, already made by others, pay a few bucks and don't think about it so much.

- [Where are some good places to find royalty free stock images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115)
- [Where can I get images for commercial use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6799)

Comment: I agree with your first bullet (at the top).... but the second one is a "yes" unless you are a complete dullard who *wants* to lose it all - but the key is you *hire* someone that knows what they are doing.

Comment: Yes, just that the OP wrote from a diy perspective. You can obviously hire people if you can't do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a computer or any software to learn how to draw. I would suggest you learn how to draw first, then you can think about learning software. Software is certainly useful for graphic designers and illustrators, but the skill comes before the software. Software is only a tool, and a tool in unskilled hands is practically useless. If you give me a scalpel, I know that I can cut things with it, but that doesn't make me a surgeon.

Have a look at "The Beginner's Fashion Design Studio by Christopher Hart". He also has a [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrd1j_IoMQDv_MEEGKLoFJg). I have no affiliation with Christopher Hart or the publishers. There are numerous similar publications and youtubers with amazing drawing tutorials on the subject.

Once you have a drawing, and if it's already good enough quality, then it's possible to just scan it and use that as your artwork.

Alternatively, you could learn how to use graphics software to ink and colour a scanned rough sketch. I would recommend vector image editing software if you want to create line art. If you have money to burn, then Adobe Illustrator is excellent. If you have no money, then Inkscape is free and Open Source.

It's also possible to draw/paint using raster image editing software such as Photoshop, or free and open source software such as GIMP, Krita or MyPaint, but then you'll probably need a graphics tablet and stylus, because trying to draw or paint with a mouse is a hopeless task.

Note that design software such as Adobe Illustrator, Adobe Photoshop, Inskcape, GIMP and Krita all have a fairly steep learning curve, so be prepared to spend quite a lot of time learning them.

There are also lots of drawing apps available for iPad or Android tablets, so that's also another possible route.