# Where are some good places to find free illustrations?

Tags: illustration, free, royalty-free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are some good places to find free stock images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-free-stock-images)

I'm looking for good places to find illustrations (not photos). Any places online with free illustrations that you would recommend? I'm looking for "Caricatures", backgrounds, cartoonish.

Answer (score 0):

http://thenounproject.com/ is ok, though probably not the kind of illustrations you're looking for. If you're looking for more clipart and color type things, that's a bit more difficult, and usually requires purchase or a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I like to browse Wikimedia Commons. That's all in a free license and it contains a lot of high-quality images. At [google images advanced search](http://www.google.com/advanced_image_search) you can also search by license.