# License that allows me completely free commercial usage of images

Tags: icon, svg, free

### PROBLEM:

I need free images for my application. They are intended for controls ( main window / buttons / treeview icons ... ).

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:

Searching through Internet, I was able to find many sites with "free" icons.

They are all licensed somehow ( GPL , Creative Commons and so on... ), but I know nothing about those licenses so I am afraid to download the images. I just do not know what I can use and what I can not, and reading through the description of those licenses did not help much.

### QUESTIONS:

*IMPORTANT INTRODUCTORY REMARKS:*

I am allowed to give credit to the designer, but since this is a desktop application the only things that cross my mind are the following:

1. Put designer's link into source code;
2. Add a clearly visible button ( on the main window ) that will open user's browser with the designer's page;

*I really do not know what else can I do to give credit, since this is my first time facing this task.*

*ACTUAL QUESTION:*

When searching for free icons for commercial use, which license should I look for ( which license corresponds to my conditions from the *INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION* section ) ?

*I apologize if the question is inappropriate, I have no intention of disrespecting other people's work. This is my first time facing this problem and I just have no money to pay for the images at the moment.*

If further information is required, leave a comment and I will update my post as soon as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are some good places to find royalty free stock images?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-royalty-free-stock-images)

Comment: I think the real question here is less about a website, and more about what the different licenses mean and how to use them. You should try editing your question to focus on that instead since it sounds like any website you get will be met with your standard response, "but I don't understand its license." So ask about that instead. Just realize we're not attorneys.

Comment: @Ryan: I have edited my post per your suggestions the best I could ( English is not my native ). Thank you for constructive suggestion. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FREE IMAGES you can go with these links....

http://www.sxc.hu/

http://www.freeimages.co.uk/

http://www.freefoto.com/

http://www.morguefile.com/

For ICONS.........

http://www.iconfinder.com/

http://www.pinvoke.com/

http://thenounproject.com/

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will check these links as soon as possible!

Comment: Iconfinder did the job for icons, as for SVG files OpenClipart saved the day. Thank you for your help. Best regards 'till next time...

Comment: Here one more site u can get icons in SVG Format...its help me a lot    http://thenounproject.com/

Answer (score 8):

> but I know nothing about those licenses

You have to read them. :)

But yes, those are but two examples of licenses that often allow you to freely use them. GPL is an open source license. Creative Commons is not, and will have different stipulations based on the type of license.

Crediting in source code wouldn't typically meet the needs of licenses that require credit, but again, you need to read the license to know for sure.

If you are looking for icons, there are many options. Google 'open source icons' for several choices.

A popular one these days is [the Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/pricing/). They have both open source and commercial icons available. It's relatively inexpensive to get licenses for the commercial offerings so in the long run, you might be saving time (and therefor money) by simply going with purchasing a commercial license for icons.

Comment: Unfortunately I am in a difficult financial situation at the moment, hence the question ( I really need free icons... ). Reading through some of those licenses did not answer all of my concerns, so I asked here to be 100% sure. Thank you for answering. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Free does not imply you can do anything you want. Some free licenses are so hard on you that you wish you could pay for the privilege. Free can come with all kinds of conditions. Such as having to print a thousand names in your flyer.