# How to find sets of images for collages?

Tags: images, resource-recommendations, stock-images, royalty-free

Is there any place with good sets of free jpgs or pngs for use in collages or just any work in general?

I see so many great collages and work in general with a lot of great images incorporated, but I just don't know where to get started doing so for myself.  I mean yes you could obviously search through thousands of images for the right one to cut out, but is there any site where you can find pre-made sets of images?  I found a few on Deviantart.  I'm personally mostly looking for illustrations of any type to use in collages.

Thanks again!

Comment: I edited your post to make it less opinion based. Feel free to edit it again if you'd like anything to be changed :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no site that collects sets of images just for the use in collages.

There are two main types of collages: one where only a few images are used in a particular format to create a layout or shape and one where a whole lot of images are put together to create another image.

For the first type, the content is more important than the color. As such, you pretty much just have to manually look through stock photos with good searches. To make that easier, you look for good resources on our related question [Where are some good places to find royalty free stock images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/115/23061)

Sometimes using Google's [search by image](https://images.google.com/) can get some pretty good visually similar images to the one that you start out with. Search by image is particularly useful if you're creating a collage of the second type where the color is more important than the content. If you find that the majority of the search is good, you could save some time by writing some sort of script to automate the URL collection, but how to write it is somewhat off topic for this answer.