# Adobe InDesign: support of Hawaiian

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts

Aloha. I need tabloid or small-newspaper designing software, and after researching, Adobe InDesign looks to be the most suitable.

*My question is*: I'll need to use a lot of Hawaiian fonts, graphics and symbols - the language for the tabloid will be entirely Hawaiian - which I'm confident I'll be able to use because so many fonts are available with InDesign.

However, I already have dozens of pages of Hawaiian language docs, and if I copy a Word document with these symbols (āēīōū) into an InDesign format, will the symbol be deleted?  There are hundreds of them and I don't want to have to go back and retype them all.

Also, I'll need a lot of Hawaiian graphics.  Does InDesign have those?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the characters as long as the font supports them. InDesign does not have any graphics that come with the software. you will either have to make them yourself or find them on stock websites.

Comment: Can you recommend a website where I can find Hawaiian graphics?  Mahalo ā nui

Comment: @Susan check out this question [Where are some good places to find royalty free stock images?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-royalty-free-stock-images) Besides that you can just Google "Stock websites." You will most likely have to search by the keyword "Hawaii" and not something too specific like "Mahalo ā nui"

Comment: I did just that--googled Hawaiian graphic art and I found a lot of free Hawaiian clip art.  I'd like to use a Hawaiian tribal graphic for the borders, but all the ones I saw black.  I suppose I could copy and paste the graphic into InDesign, but can you change the color of the clip art once it's in InDesign?

Comment: @Susan Not in InDesign itself, no. You can open/copy-paste the clip art in Illustrator (assuming it's vector), recolour it there, and then place the Illustrator file in your InDesign document. It will be updatable if you change the colours in Illustrator later on.