# Metal sheet with diamond pattern

Tags: website-design, copyright, metal

I'm not sure if this question is for this website and if it's not can someone point me in the right direction but what I want is a picture/texture of a metal sheet with that tall or long diamond shape on. And if possible I want to put it on a website so copyright may be a issue

Comment: Hi Nicholas, welcome to GD.SE! Are you looking to create the image yourself? If yes, could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. Or are you looking for a stock image? There are a plethora of stock websites that have photos of real sheet metal and digital patterns for websites.

Comment: I'm not a arty guy  so that's why I came here so can you tell me what a "stock photo" is please?

Comment: @Nicholas: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_photography): ***Stock photography is the supply of photographs**, which are often licensed for specific uses. It is used to fulfill the needs of creative assignments instead of hiring a photographer, often for a lower cost. Today, stock images can be presented in searchable online databases.*

Comment: Is there a free version of this and if there is can I get a link please?

Comment: Sometimes patterns can be free but they usually require that you link back to the site that you got them from. http://subtlepatterns.com/ is a pretty good website for website patterns. You can view one of our threads for a list of stock websites - [Where are some good places to find royalty free stock images?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-royalty-free-stock-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Google and do an image search for "Diamond Plate Texture" (or pattern)

Click on the Search Tools tab

Select "Labeled for reuse"

[image: screenshot]

You can also use the Size option, to find larger images, if you need one.

Comment: @Nicholas please note that google does quite sometimes get the licensing issue wrong. So please check the site before use. But yes this is a classic 3D texturing need so its readily available also as bump, displacement and normal maps.

Comment: I had no idea what "that tall or long diamond shape" was referring to! Makes perfect sense now.