# What are some good places to find multiple stock images from the same location?

Tags: resource-recommendations, stock-images

I need photos that look like they came from the same location. Is there a place that has "albums" of this sort? Royalty free, creative commons licensed, or paid.

Comment: Usually when you find a stock photo, you can find the other stock photos from the photographers photoshoot. This works for some type of photos more than others, like it works for people and objects and not so much for places in my experience. I have seen this on most stock websites. Can you be more specific on the type of collection of stock photos you're looking for?

Comment: Most location-specific stock images use the location as a keyword. So searching stock sites for the location name results in images from that location. I'm not really certain what you are asking.

Comment: Some options are Unsplash and Freepik.

Comment: [related](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/115/34253)